# Why isn't brightness not reduceing after OS install?

Tags: windows-7, brightness

I installed new OS (Windows 7 Professional 64bit) in my laptop with no graphic card (removed). Downloaded all the drivers.

Everything is working fine except the brightness. Its stuck at full brightness. I tried many third party apps but still didn't work. What to do now?

(On pressing the <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> it shows brightness with 1 bar and on pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> no bar is shown but nothing changes. Brightness is still full)

Comment: Are your BIOS up to date?

Comment: @CharlieRB Idk.. How to update so?

Comment: Go to the web site of the manufacturer of your computer. Download the update for your model and follow the instructions provided.

Comment: What update should I download? I already downloaded all the drivers for my VAIO Laptop

Comment: Update the BIOS if there is an update available.

Answer (score 0):

Se if you can decrease brightness on Controlpanel -> Power Options: Adjust the display brightness. Maybe you have to check some options there.

EDIT:

Try this:
Start -> Control Panel -> Hardware and Sound -> Device Manager.
In the Device Manager window, look for “Monitors”, then right-click your monitor and select “Uninstall”. Be sure to also check the “Remove driver” option. Once removed, click the “Scan for hardware changes” icon

Comment: No such option  "Adjust the display brightness" nor any other :(

Comment: @VipulPriyadarshi Have you checked in device manager if your monitor is properly installed, or installed drivers for your monitor?

Comment: Yes @zaonline... under display adapters it shows Standard VGA Graphics Adapter and under monitor its shows Generic PnP Monitor and both of them are working properly as it shows.

Comment: even if I update, it shows its up to date...